# What is the difference between these three prepositional phrases? "...high by/from/with (smoking) weed"

Tags: prepositions

> Can you get high **by** smoking weed?
> Can you get high **from** smoking weed?
> Can you get high **with** smoking weed?

> Can you get high **by** weed?
> Can you get high **from** weed?
> Can you get high **with** weed?

Comment: Rather than fight this, just drop the preposition. "Can you get high smoking weed?"

Comment: With all of the weed smoking you mention, I'm surprised you care about the difference in prepositions.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you get high **with** smoking weed?

is usually not said, the structure implies that the name is "smoking weed", whereas it is usually called only "weed".

However,

> Can you get high **by** smoking weed?
>   Can you get high **from** smoking weed?

is understood to ask about the effects of "weed".

> Can you get high **from** weed?
>   Can you get high **with** weed?

Also have the same meaning as the previous two questions, however "smoking" is implied, whereas

> Can you get high by weed?

sounds awkward, usually "by" is followed by an action, e.g. "**by** smoking".